# Find a blank row from thousands of rows

Tags: regex, notepad, ultraedit

I have around 2 million of rows need to find all the empty rows.

```
AKRAM          AHMED
SSYED          Aakram     ahmed
(need to find this empty row)
james          hetfield     metallica
```

Comment: Using which program/technology?

Comment: what language are you coding in?

Comment: line1 (spaces)AKRAM(feild lenght for akram is say 15spaces,5 already used so after 10 spaces its ahmed)AHMED

Comment: I have fixed length file

Comment: AKRAM          AHMED
SSYED          Aakram     ahmed
(need to find this empty row)
james          hetfield     metallica

Comment: if you read the file line by line, test each line with the regular expression `^[[:space:]]*$`.

Comment: it doesnt seem to work

Comment: After syed they are spaces! so if use a regexp then it finds this space! but what I need to find is that one empty row!

Answer (score 1):

Search for this regex : `\\n\s*\\n`

It will search for lines containing only white spaces or nothing.

Comment: I believe you don't need to double escape the new line: `\n` should be enough.

Answer (score 0):

```
/^\s*$/ #will match only line containing spaces or nothing.
```